# Find peaks of data

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table Integrations.

| Inte | Start Date | End Date | Total_Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INT1 | 1/7/2021 7:16:00 | 1/7/2021 9:22:00 | 02:06:00 |
| INt2 | 2/7/2021 3:48:00 | 2/7/2021 5:10:00 | 01:22:00 |

Output I need:

| Running Time | No of Inte. |
| --- | --- |
| 1/7/2021 7:00:00 | 1 |
| 1/7/2021 8:00:00 | 1 |
| 1/7/2021 9:00:00 | 1 |
| 2/7/2021 4:00:00 | 1 |
| 2/7/2021 5:00:00 | 1 |

Basically it want to plot the peak hour when most Integrations were running.

Sql query I wrote:

```
select time, sum(value) as No_of_Inte
 from(
       select round(Start_Date, 'HH24') as time, count(*) as value
        from Integrations
        group by Start_Date
     )
group by time
order by time asc
```

But this does not consider Total Duration.
Output :

| Running Time | No of Inte. |
| --- | --- |
| 1/7/2021 7:00:00 | 1 |
| 2/7/2021 4:00:00 | 1 |

Also, new Integrations are added every day.

Comment: Is your database MySql or Oracle?  You've tagged both

Comment: Create a tally table of intervals of interest. Left join your data to the tally.

Comment: @Martin Its oracle db.

Comment: @Serg Can you explain with an example. I am a beginner with Sql.

Comment: Some side observations:  What is the data type of START_DATE and END_DATE? If it is VARCHAR2 (as most of the suggested answers assume), then that is a design fail. Dates should be stored as DATE, which is an internal binary type.  The client can always format as needed.  Second, since you are storing start and end date (which includes time) you should not also store TOTAL_DURATION.  This can and should be calculated at run time, as end_date - start_date.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a recursive query. First create the test data

```
CREATE TABLE integrations (inte,start_date, end_date)
AS
(
SELECT 'INT1', TO_DATE('1/7/2021 7:16:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('1/7/2021 9:22:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'INT2', TO_DATE('2/7/2021 3:48:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2/7/2021 5:10:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual 
);
```

Now use a recursive query to loop through the hours between start and end date. Then group by hour to get the correct counts per hour.

```
WITH row_per_hours (id, run_hour, end_date) AS
(
  SELECT inte,
         TRUNC(start_date,'HH24'),
         end_date
   FROM integrations
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         run_hour + INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
         end_date
    FROM row_per_hours
    WHERE run_hour + INTERVAL '1' HOUR < end_date
  
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(run_hour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as running_time,
       COUNT(id) as integration_count
  FROM row_per_hours 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(run_hour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ORDER BY 1;


RUNNING_TIME        INTEGRATION_COUNT
------------------- -----------------
01/07/2021 07:00:00                 1
01/07/2021 08:00:00                 1
01/07/2021 09:00:00                 1
02/07/2021 03:00:00                 1
02/07/2021 04:00:00                 1
02/07/2021 05:00:00                 1
```

Comment: @PranjalJadhav If feel some answer is good enough you may upvote that answer to indicate it as useful or accept it if it fits your needs well. You may check [A very short Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

For 12C and above:

You may use lateral join to generate required number of rows per each interval. Since it looks like you need some rounding of dates towards neares hour, I've added `round` instead of `trunc`. Or is there any other reason for the first interval is treating `7:00` as inclusion?.

> ```
> with a(Inte, start_dt, end_dt) as (
>   select
>     'INT1'
>     , to_date('1/7/2021 07:16:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
>     , to_date('1/7/2021 09:22:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
>   from dual union all
>   select
>     'INt2'
>     , to_date('2/7/2021 03:48:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
>     , to_date('2/7/2021 05:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
>   from dual
> )
> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */
>   b.hour_
>   , count(1) as int_cnt
> from a
>   outer apply (
>     select
>       round(a.start_dt + numtodsinterval(level - 1, 'HOUR'), 'hh24') as hour_
>     from dual
>     connect by round(start_dt, 'hh24') + numtodsinterval(level - 1, 'HOUR') <= trunc(end_dt, 'hh24')
>   ) b
> group by b.hour_
> order by 1
> ```
>
> ```
> HOUR_               | INT_CNT
> :------------------ | ------:
> 2021-07-01 07:00:00 |       1
> 2021-07-01 08:00:00 |       1
> 2021-07-01 09:00:00 |       1
> 2021-07-02 04:00:00 |       1
> 2021-07-02 05:00:00 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0701e09238ccb1c6f15eb92483fa3be8)*

Comment: @APC Thank you. I used to indicate Oracle's version when some "new" (as my most used version was 11.2) features required, but this time it was unintentionally lost. Updated my response with it